# Firebase SMS Password Reset

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, sms-verification

How can users reset their passwords with a phone number in Firebase IOS?
Phone Registration is possible in Firebase but what is if a user is logged out and forgot his verification code?

Language: Swift

Answer (score 0):

A user only has to enter the verification code once, they don't need to remember it beyond that.

But if the verification status is lost, or if you want to reverify the phone number for some reason, you can just [call `verifyPhoneNumber`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone) again to start another verification cycle.